# How to remove empty space from CSS animation

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

I am trying to create a marquee style banner that displays logos moving horizontally. I've got the css animation and keyframes down but before the next iteration there's blank space that I want to remove. How can i make the marquee loop continuously without any empty space or breaks?

Comment: Welcome. Please show your code if you want help.

Comment: .marquee-content{
 list-style: none;
display: inline-flex;
align-content: stretch;
animation: moving 12s linear infinite;}

@keyframes moving {
 0% {transform: translateX(50vw);}
 100% {transform: translateX(-100vw);}
}

Comment: You may have to change defaults to `margin:0; padding:0` And `box-sizing:'border-box'`

Comment: Thanks for providing the code in your comment; can you please [edit] your question, and put your code in your question, so all the details are in the same place.